# azure-ad-b2c - How to prevent reuse of Oauth Authorization Code?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using the  [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow#2-get-an-access-token) , but I noticed that I'm able to reuse the same authorization code and the server responds with a new id token.

And as per OAuth 2.0 specifications, The client MUST NOT reuse the same authorization code (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.2)

Am I missing any settings in my policy? The only documentation that I found about code authorization code flow in AzureB2C is the following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-tokens?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#authorization-code-lifetime

[image: POSTMAN]

Edited:

I generated the auth-code by using below endpoint:

```
https://tenant.b2clogin.com/tenant/policy/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=clientid&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&scope=openid&response_mode=query&code_challenge=codechallenge&code_challenge_method=S256
```

I generated the access token by using parameters like below:

[image]

But still able to generate tokens using same code

[image]

Here's my new app:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using a nonce claim, this expected behavior due to a known limitation with B2C.

According to the [RFC (6749) - The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

The authentication code should be used one time.

With standard Azure AD, a fix was released in 2018:

[Azure Active Directory breaking changes reference | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-breaking-changes#authorization-codes-can-no-longer-be-reused)

This is because B2C is stateless and does not follow the OTP RFC standard here. Standard Azure AD made engineering provisions to track and invalidate AuthZ codes back in 2018, but Azure AD B2C has not completed this work yet. B2C would have to become a stateful service and this is a significant investment. So while this is a known issue, this work is not completed at this time.

A workaround is to use the [nonce claim](https://medium.com/@benjamin.botto/oauth-replay-attack-mitigation-18655a62fe53).

See also: [B2C nonce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69778543/azure-ad-b2c-missing-nonce-in-oauth2-v2-0-token-end-point-for-client-credential)

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the error like below when I tried to reuse the auth-code:***

[image]

I created an **Azure AD B2C application** and added **SPA** redirect Uri like below:

[image]

I generated the **auth-code** by using below endpoint:

```
https://tenant.b2clogin.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/policy/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=RedirectUri
&response_mode=query
&scope=scope
&state=state
&code_challenge=codechallenge
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

[image]

I generated the **access token** by using parameters like below:

```json
https://tenant.b2clogin.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/policy/oauth2/v2.0/token 

grant_type=authorization_code
&client_id=ClientID
&scope=scope
&redirect_uri=redirectUri
&code_verifier=codeverifier
```

[image]

When I tried to reuse the code, I got the error as below:

[image]

> **Note** that: By default, the auth-code lifetime in Azure AD B2C is 10 minutes, and it cannot be changed.

- By default, Azure AD B2C will not generate the token if the auth-code is already used.
- Make sure to use https to transmit the auth-code.
- While generating the auth-code make sure to receive the prompt while signing in by using **`prompt`** in the authorize endpoint.
- If still the issue persists, try by registering a new application and check.

**Reference:**

[Updates and breaking changes - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-breaking-changes#october-2018)

Comment: Thanks. I follow your instructions but still no luck, I even created a new app but was still able to reuse auth code. I have edited my post with the new info.

Comment: For the second time you are clicking on send to generate tokens is it working?

Comment: yep, it's working fine. I can click how many times I want and it still generates a new token, the only time that I get an error is when the code expires (~10 minutes after I get auth code)